# PhoneGap - How to create a new file in iOS documents folder

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

How is it possible to use PhoneGap to create/make a new file in the iOS app documents folder?
I need this file to be a .wav as I'm going to use it as the source to record some audio.

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343204/create-a-directory-in-phonegap-application
I hope it help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look a PhoneGap API Documention. It is full of examples. This one should interest you (Full Example)

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

Comment: Thanks yeah I check the docs but couldn't quite make sense of it at first.  Managed to get it sorted in the end.