# Create a Directory in PhoneGap Application

Tags: mobile, cordova, filesystems, directory

Trying to figure out how to create a directory on the file system using PhoneGap.

I want to create a directory for my PhoneGap application, so I can store images the user creates there and load them back up in the app.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is how you do it :

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null); 

function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) { 
        var entry=fileSystem.root; 
        entry.getDirectory("example", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail); 
} 

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) { 
      console.log("Created dir "+dir.name); 
} 

function onGetDirectoryFail(error) { 
     console.log("Error creating directory "+error.code); 
}
```

On iOS, this script will create a directory named 'example' in Applications/YOUR_APP/Documents/

Comment: yep, that works.  I was just about to answer my question since I found that as well.  Funny how I can't find an answer until I post it on SO, then I find it immediately.

Comment: @JohnSonmez Which code do you use to save the image?

Comment: @titouan-de-baileul does it require some extenal sources

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. I added `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />`, `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>` and `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>` to my config.xml but still it's not working :(

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me (based on version 7 Cordova documentation - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html):

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('cdvfile://localhost/persistent/',
  function fileEntryCallback(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.getDirectory('my_directory', { create: true });
  }
);
```

> If the code above doesn't work, you may need to reinstall the File and File Transfer plugins. A command like `console.log(window.resolveLocalFileSystemUrl)` is one way to test that the plugins are working.

Also, if you're using Content Security Policy (CSP) be sure your `default-src` allows `cdvfile:` paths:

`default-src cdvfile:`