# Create a directory in data/data/{package_name} Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems

Is this possible? I had a look at other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343204/create-a-directory-in-phonegap-application) but I am using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///data/data/{package_name}", onSuccess, onError);`

therefore the object I get back from `onSuccess` callback does not have the 'root' so the following will fail:

```
function onSuccess(fileSystem) { 
    var entry=fileSystem.root; 
    entry.getDirectory("example", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail); 
}
```

because `fileSystem.root` is undefined.

I assume it is not currently possible in Phonegap?

Edit: I am already writing files in data/data successfully using Phonegap, in subdirectories of Files folder I created using native code, like:

Files/images
Files/videos
Files/audios

I would like to create images/my_sub_folder or videos/my_subfolder

Comment: how do you write in data/data? Please provide a response here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652193/cordova-3-x-phonegap-write-on-data-data-generates-encodingexception

Answer (score 0):

as for me, I use plugin to write any data to system. Js only make a calls to plugins (DB, IO, Service, etc) all work with enviroment makes native logic, JS only recive data through callbacks to show it.

Comment: which plugin? I mentioned Phonegap and Android in the title, please elaborate.

Comment: <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" /> here is more info http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

It's because `resolveLocalFileSystemURI` pass a `DirectoryEntry` object to the success callback and not a `FileSystem` object. It's like you already get `fileSystem.root`.