# cordova 3.x (phonegap) - write on /data/data generates encodingException

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to write a file on my application memory using the following code taken from [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter):

```
    writeOnFileSystem : function() {
    console.log("writeOnFileSystem resolveLocalFileSystemURL ...");     
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}
};

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
fileSystem.root.getFile("file:///data/data/com.company.app/readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
 ...
}

function fail(error) {
  console.log(error.code);
 }
```

This throws such exception:

*05-14 12:16:55.704: W/System.err(27827): org.apache.cordova.file.EncodingException: This path has an invalid ":" in it.*

I am using this string to access my /data/data:
**file:///data/data/com.company.app/readme.txt** (com.company.app is the package of my app)

- Is this the proper way to access my /data/data?

The same code works if I write on my SD which is done by default on Android.

I am using:

Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.1

org.apache.cordova.file 1.0.1 "File"

org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.4-dev "File Transfer"

JQM

eclipse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** while this answer still holds, there are quite a few changes to the [Cordova File API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#android-file-system-layout)

Anyway,

When you call `requestFileSystem` it returns a 
`FileSystem` object which has a root property which is a `DirectoryEntry`.

When you call `resolveLocalFileSystemURI` it returns a `DirectoryEntry` or 
`FileEntry`.

So in your case you need to do:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///data/data/{package_name}", onSuccess, onError); 

function onSuccess(entry) { 
    entry.getDirectory("example", {create: true, exclusive: false},onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail); 
}
function onError(error){
console.log(error);
}
```

the method `resolveLocalFileSystemURI` will give you access to the /data/data folder, then you go from there.

The problem with `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);` is that on Android it will give you the SD card path if there is an SD card mounted on the device, otherwise it will give you the path to the internal storage (not even sure if data/data/{package_name} or somewhere else). If you ask me, this is one of the most stupid design choices of all times

Comment: I solved it by myself but still find your help important and unique because the support on phonegap with SO seems to be very poor.

Comment: Thanks, I do agree Phonegap/Cordova support is poor. You also might want to try the official forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap

Comment: To get the working path like "/data/data/<app_id>/files" simply use cordova.file.dataDirectory as a javascript variable, eg:
var cordova.file.dataDirectory + '/test.txt';

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#android-file-system-layout

Comment: @user824963 I edited my answer, when OP asked the question the API was different, now it is way easier to get hold of a folder/file