# phonegap : manipulate files system

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I curently develop an application for android and ios with phonegap. So I want to create folders and files in the files system of android and ios. How can I check if files exist and create my files in specific folder? And after that, how can I load them? all files I want to create and manipulate are JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve your goals you need this Cordova/Phonegap plugin:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

This plugin supports both Android and iOS platform.

Comment: How I though it was native. Thanks a lot. Now can I use function like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343204/create-a-directory-in-phonegap-application ??

Comment: All function I test doesn't work. I have add plugin and right... Did I fail the syntaxe?

Comment: You have to check carefully the documentation: file system operations need sometimes configuration for specific platform (Android, iOS, ...) or permissions